# ldap_search_sW function crashing on Windows Server 2012 R2 X64?

Tags: delphi, ldap, delphi-7

For searching for a particular user in Active Directory Services, we have used `ldap_search_sW` API. It is however , crashing my exe in case of Windows Server 2012. No error code is returned , the EXE just stops working.

THe EXE i have is 32 bit application. So i guess it will load from "SysWow64" directory. Here is a sample line as to how the calling is done :-

Declaration of pld :

```
type // record declaration begins
  {$EXTERNALSYM PLDAP}
  PLDAP = ^LDAP;
  {$EXTERNALSYM LDAP}
  LDAP = record

      ld_sb: record
        sb_sd: ULONG;
        Reserved1: array [0..(10 * sizeof(ULONG))] of Byte;
       sb_naddr: ULONG;   // notzero implies CLDAP available
       Reserved2: array [0..(6 * sizeof(ULONG)) - 1] of Byte;
       //
       //  Following parameters MAY match up to reference implementation of LDAP
      //

    ld_host: PChar;
    ld_version: ULONG;
    ld_lberoptions: Byte;

    //
   //  Safe to assume that these parameters are in same location as
   //  reference implementation of LDAP API.
   //

    ld_deref: ULONG;

    ld_timelimit: ULONG;
    ld_sizelimit: ULONG;

    ld_errno: ULONG;
    ld_matched: PChar;
    ld_error: PChar;
    ld_msgid: ULONG;

    Reserved3: array  [0..(6*sizeof(ULONG))] of Byte;

    //
    //  Following parameters may match up to reference implementation of LDAP API.
    //

    ld_cldaptries: ULONG;
    ld_cldaptimeout: ULONG;
    ld_refhoplimit: ULONG;
    ld_options: ULONG;

end; // record declaration end

 pld : PLDAP;
 pld := Session.pld; // session PLD is assigned as is to it
 The sessions' PLD is initialized as 
 ldappld := ldap_initW(PWideChar(ldapServerW), ldapPort)  // this is eventually assigned to Session's PLD which is assigned to the PLD used Below

 LdapCheck(ldap_search_sW(pld, PWideChar('DC=esbs,DC=local'), LDAP_SCOPE_SUBTREE, '(objectCategory=user)', nil, 0, plmSearch));
```

WHat steps should i take ?

Here is the windows dump of the EXE crash :

```
 Problem signature:
Problem Event Name: APPCRASH
Application Name:   project1.exe
Application Version:    0.1.1.0
Application Timestamp:  2a425e19
Fault Module Name:  KERNELBASE.dll
Fault Module Version:   6.2.8400.0
Fault Module Timestamp: 4fb7184e
Exception Code: 000006ba
Exception Offset:   00017945
OS Version: 6.2.8400.2.0.0.400.8
Locale ID:  1033
Additional Information 1:   91d0
Additional Information 2:   91d025961d4c758a8b5ea7ee1390f3b7
Additional Information 3:   c3ce
Additional Information 4:   c3cebe78f080ab69603c33ad36d75750
```

Declaration of function:

```
    {$EXTERNALSYM ldap_search_sW}
  function ldap_search_sW(ld: PLDAP; base: PWideChar; scope: ULONG; filter, attrs: PWideChar;   attrsonly: ULONG;  var res: PLDAPMessage): ULONG; cdecl;
```

Comment: @DavidHeffernan : I was trying different things.

Comment: I must confess, I'm stumped by that exception code. Do you have anything like madExcept in the app to gather diagnostics?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan : I have Eureka Log 6 . Should i attach it to the project and then try ?

Comment: I would certainly recommend that.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I tried attaching Eureka Log , and Mad Except , Seperately. Both times , the exe crashed and no dialog was generated by either of them. only the windows dialog was shown

Comment: Could you possible show your declaration of `ldap_search_sW`, and how you declared the variables. Also show the call that initialises `pld`. Finally, which version of Delphi.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan : I have added the declarations and definitions in the question. BTW, the DLL is statically linked. I tried loading it dynamically via LoadLibrary. It did not changed anything

Comment: That's not what quite what I'm looking for. How about the call that initialises `pld`. And your records got mangled. Please can you sort that out.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan : sorry for the mess up. corrected now

Comment: OK, but I still cannot see where pld is initialised. I mean somewhere you must be initialising the struct.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan : I have added further code.

Comment: Thanks. I cannot find anything untoward in any of that.

Comment: Removing LDAPCheck does not change anything .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have solved the issue and I am posting the solution here. There was no issue in the `ldap_search_sW` function that we were using . Before connecting to the ADS, we used to authenticate the user Name and password provided. Then we used `ldap_initW` , `ldap_set_optionW` and `ldap_simple_bind_sW` to connect to the server .

Then users list is read by `ldap_search_sW` to read the Users list. 
In Server 2012, if authentication part was skipped, the exe did not crash .
The authentication was done as :-

```
function AuthenticateADSUserW(ADSUserName, ADSPassword, ADSip: String;Var Fun_Obj:String): Boolean;
var
   AuthResult : Integer;
   hInstance:    THandle;
   ADSServerName,
   ADSUsrNam,
   ADSPwd,
   ADSPortNo,
   Error: Array [0..255] of char;
   ldapDomain,
   ldapUserName,
   ldapPassword    : WideString;
   hr            : integer;
   obj           : IADs;
 begin
   try
     Result  := False;
         Fun_Obj := '';
// Insert code to securely retrieve the user name and password.
try
    ldapDomain    := UTF8Decode(ADSip);
    ldapUserName  := UTF8Decode(ADSUserName);
    ldapPassword  := UTF8Decode(ADSPassword);

    CoInitialize(Nil); //Added By Sameer

    hr := ADsOpenObject('LDAP://'+ldapDomain,
                       ldapUserName,
                       ldapPassword,
                       ADS_SECURE_AUTHENTICATION,
                       IADs,
                       obj);
    Fun_Obj := obj.ADsPath ;
    if  Succeeded(hr) then
      Result := True;

except
  on e : exception do
  begin
    escan.Updatelog('Error '+e.ClassName + ': ' + e.Message,1,0);
      Result := False;
  end;
  //lblMessage.Caption  := e.ClassName + ': ' + #13#10 + e.Message;
end;
finally
   CoUninitialize;
 end;
end;
```

We skipped this and instead authenticated by retrieving the Base DN of the provided username . If BASE DN is returned, the user is considered authenticated. If returned empty, the user is not authenticated.

Hope it helps someone.